# transform json in aws athena

Tags: sql, json, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a table called `Game`, with a `history` jsonb column. The json looks like this:

```
{"Games": {"key1": "value1", "key2": value2}}
```

(the values can be a string or a number).
I want to transform it to a json of this format:

```
{"Games": "AllGames": [{"key1": ["value1"]}, {"key2": ["value2"}]]}
```

The original `json` has one value for each key, which transform to an array with one field in the new `json`, as a string, even if the original value was a number.

I have this working code in `postgres`, for cases when `history` is not null:

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object(
        'Games', jsonb_build_object(
                'AllGames', jsonb_agg(
                        jsonb_build_object(
                                key, json_build_array(CASE
                                                          WHEN value::text LIKE '"%"' THEN value
                                                          ELSE (concat('"',value::text,'"'))::jsonb
                            END)
                        )
                                )
               )
                     )
FROM
    (
        SELECT jsonb_each(history::jsonb->'Games').*
        FROM public.Game
    ) sub
```

But I'm not sure how to do it in Athena.

Tried to transform the `json`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve that. In basis of almost all of them would be using ability to cast JSON to some type (for example JSON object -> `map(varchar, json)`) and back. For example using some concatenation (to remove some `map` creation):

```sql
WITH dataset(json_str) AS
(
   values ('{"Games": {"key1": "value1", "key2": 1}}')
)

SELECT '{"Games": { "AllGames": '
        || json_format(
          cast(
             map_values(
               transform_values(
                       cast(
                         json_extract(json_str, '$.Games') -- read the inner object as JSON type 
                           as map(varchar, json)
                       ) -- cast it to map
                   , (k,v) -> map(array[k], array[ array[v] ]) -- transform map values to another map
               )
             ) -- read array of transformed map values 
              as json) -- cast it to JSON
           ) -- format JSON to string
        || '}}'
FROM dataset;
```

Output:

```
                            _col0                             
--------------------------------------------------------------
 {"Games": { "AllGames": [{"key1":["value1"]},{"key2":[1]}]}}
```